# Does Liveness Probes restart or kill the Pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I had read on the documentation that liveness probes make a new pod and stop the other one. But in the kubernetes dashboard it shows me only restarts with my tcp livness probe. I was wondering what kubernetes does during a liveness probe. Can i control it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kubelet uses [liveness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) to know when to **restart a Container**, not recreate the pods.

Probes have a number of fields that you can use to more precisely control the behavior of the checks (`initialDelaySeconds`,`periodSeconds`, `timeoutSeconds`, `successThreshold` and `failureThreshold`). You can find details about them [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes).

For container restart, SIGTERM is first sent with waits for a parameterized grace period, and then Kubernetes sends SIGKILL. You can control some of this behavior by tweaking the [`terminationGracePeriodSeconds`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#podspec-v1-core) value and/or  [Attaching Handlers to Container Lifecycle Events](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/).

---

Update:

The Kubernetes v1.28.x has [a proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-node/2238-liveness-probe-grace-period) to add a new field exclusive for tweaking the probes:

> Liveness probes currently use the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` on both normal shutdown and when probes fail [...]
>
> I propose adding a new field to probes,
> `probe.terminationGracePeriodSeconds`. When set, it will override the
> `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` for liveness or startup termination, and
> will be ignored for readiness probes.